# Number of logins during hourly, each day of the week?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of data contians (yyyy-mm-dd, hh:min:ss) from this data i need to sort out how many times 'logins' was punched for any given hour of the day. and also how many times logins' was punched for each day of the week .

I tried some code but am not confident the code i have right. Also should i include `COUNT(*)` in the statement

This code for hourly logins :

```
SELECT date_time, HOUR(date_time) FROM time_logs ORDER BY DAY(date_time);
```

Code for day for week:

```
SELECT date_time, DAY(date_time) FROM time_logs ORDER BY DAY(date_time);
```

Is this is right. If not could you give me hint

Comment: If you want to know how many times of login per hour or per day, yes, you should include `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: May I ask, does the table have column like "id" or "userid" or "username"?

Answer (score 0):

To count how many logins per hour, you just need to add `COUNT(*)` in your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY HOUR(date_time)`.

```
SELECT date_time, HOUR(date_time),COUNT(*) 'Total Logins' 
FROM time_logs GROUP BY HOUR(date_time) ORDER BY DAY(date_time);
```

Similarly on your day count you need to add the same thing. Only difference is your grouping is now by day.

```
SELECT date_time, DAY(date_time), COUNT(*) 'Total Logins' 
FROM time_logs GROUP BY DAY(date_time) ORDER BY DAY(date_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your datetime to both hour and date and then group by to get your aggregations.

https://rextester.com/BQSV80644

Answer (score 0):

For hour of the day:

```
SELECT HOUR(date_time), COUNT(*)
FROM time_logs 
GROUP BY HOUR(date_time);
```

For day of the week:

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(date_time), COUNT(*)
FROM time_logs 
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(date_time)
ORDER BY MIN(date_time)
```